# I am using version 6.24.3 of jxbrowser, but unable to access some websites?

Tags: jxbrowser

I am using version 6.24.3 of jxbrowser, and there is a problem when accessing [https://mail.163.com.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrR09.png) I can confirm that there is no problem with the website. I have checked the official jxbrowser documentation, but there is no gain. I hope to get an answer here
The following is the error message given by version 6.24.3 of jxbrowser；

> This site can’t be reached
> The webpage at https://mail.163.com/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
> ERR_SPDY_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURIT。
> I want to confirm what causes this, and if there is a solution on this version?
> [Exception screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrR09.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's because of the old Chromium 69 used by JxBrowser 6.24.3. It's possible that the website doesn't work in such an old Chromium version. I can recommend that you try [JxBrowser 7.11](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser) based on Chromium 79 and see if it helps.